# How to implement job-control of shell

Tags: c++, linux, shell

Hello guys I am using C++ to implement a shell of linux, but I have some problem with the signal.

Here is the basic logic of my shell, it's the pseudocode but you can easily know what I want to do.

```
signal_handler(int sig){
  switch(sig){
    case SIGINT: ... break;
    case SIGTSTP: ... break;
  }
}

main{
  signal(SIGINT,SIG_IGN);
  signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);

  what main process do{
    wait(&child_pid);
  }
  what child process do{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);
  }
}
```

For now I am using the `wait(&fpid)` to wait for the termination of a child process.. But now I want to make a job-control feature.. What kinds of signal should I code for the waitpid?

I use `SIG_IGN` to let the main process of this shell ignore the `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-z` signal which is `SIGINT` and `SIGTSTP`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a signal_handler for the main process, which could accept the `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-z` signal, and then pass the signal to the child process.

That means the signal handler for the main process and child process should be different.